React does not save `Session` `Cookie`
I’m facing a problem. React isn’t saving Cookie in the cookie storage of the site

My API is running on Flask and has these settings:
# ------------- Flask App ------------- 
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='templates/static')
app.secret_key = 'secret'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'] = True
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = False
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True  # Nur über HTTPS
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True  # Nicht über JavaScript zugänglich
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'Lax'  # Schutz vor CSRF
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True

@app.after_request
def add_security_headers(response):
  response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  # response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' 
  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/ https://cdn.discordapp.com/; style-src 'self' 
  https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/; font-src 'self' https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/; 
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
  response.headers['Strict-Transport-Security'] = 'max-age=31536000; 
  includeSubDomains;preload'
  response.headers['X-Content-Type-Options'] = 'nosniff'
  response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
  response.headers['Referrer-Policy'] = 'same-origin'
  return response

And this function returns the Cookie in the response:
@app.route('/oauth', methods=['GET'])
def oauth():
# Check if data ok
if membership: # If user is allowed to use App
    session['userdata'] = [id, avatar, username, usertag, membership, access_token]
    session.setdefault('filter', [None, None, None])
    return jsonify({'status': 'authorized'})

In postman all is working fine. It saves the Cookie and reuses it in the other requests, but only when I try to run it with Flask, I get authorized, and retrieve the Cookie, but the browser doesn’t save it, so it wont be used in the next requests.
I already tried to change the setting in Flask like in this post here: I am unable to set the cookies received from the response but it didn’t change anything.

This bug occurred in Chromium but has been fixed. See more details here. For using Cookies, see the answer below.

Postman doesn’t handle Cookies the same way Browsers do.
A Cookie with the HttpOnly attribute tells the Browser to block javascript from having access to the Cookies and only include Cookies in Requests to the domain.
If your reactjs application is running on another domain (same host different port is still another domain) and you want these Cookies to be sent along with the Request, you must allow credentials i.e. Cookies to be part of the Request.
Example using fetch():
fetch(url, {
  credentials: "include",
});
Also the Server must respond with the affirmation that it allows cross-origin HTTP Requests to include credentials by sending a Response with the Header:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
